# buscar espacios en blanco en una imagen con node.js

Tags: nodejs

Lo que quisiera es identificar cuando una imagen contiene un sello en un espacio o esta en blanco , utilicé `image-clipper` para cortar la imagen y poder comparar pixeles de color pero no me a resultado aun.

```
var Clipper = require('image-clipper');    
Clipper("Imagenes/new_format_ge.jpg")
    .crop(82, 900, 250, 70)
    .toDataURL(function(dataUrl) {
     console.log('recortada!'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Después  de varios días de buscar por halla y por acá con ayuda de algunos colaboradores , llegue a la respuesta de que para comparar pixeles en una imagen se necesita de una api llamada getpixels, pueden buscar su documentación en la web para mas aplicaciones   y les quedaría algo así:

var totalPixels=0;
            await getPixels("ruta de la imagen ", function(err, pixels) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Bad image path")
                return
            } 
console.log("got pixels", pixels.data);

Ya depende de que desean hacer con los pixeles totales , y para ayudar un poco les diré que los valores se los dan por pixel, el cual tiene 4 elementos basados en RGB y un Alpha , cualquier ayuda que pueda brindar estoy por aquí , saludos.